# Matlab - Image processing 3D image by shifting red component of 2D

Tags: matlab, image-processing, multidimensional-array

I have been assigned recently a task related to image processing. The thing is that I have no prior experience to this subject so I face some difficulties.

The concept is to create a 3D image from a 2D image by initially extracting the R,G,B components and combine them after shifting the red one according to some sort of a formula (i.e. calculate the pixel which has to be shifted by applying the formula `a = x(i,j,k)*40/max(Rcomponent(:))` to each element of the red image and replace element `x(i,j-a,k)` by the value of `x(i,j,k))`.

Here is my current progress:

```
original = imread(nameofimag); % read file
imaginfos = imfinfo(nameofimag); % identify colortype 
coltype = imaginfos(1).ColorType;
truecol = 'truecolor';

if strcmp(coltype,truecol) == 1 % convert to grayscale if needed
    originalgray = rgb2gray(original);
else
    originalgray = original;
end

Z = zeros(size(originalgray,1),size(originalgray,2));

% create red, blue, green parts

imagR = cat(3,originalgray,Z,Z);
imagG = cat(3,Z,originalgray,Z);
imagB = cat(3,Z,Z,originalgray);

imagRshifted = zeros(size(originalgray,1),size(originalgray,2));

h = waitbar(0,'Please wait...');

% shift red image

for i = 1:size(imagR,1)
    for j = 1:size(imagR,2)
        for k = 1:size(imagR,3)
            imagRshifted(i,j,k) = imagR(i,j,k);
            pixeltochange = round((imagRshifted(i,j,k)*40)...
                                                /max(original(:)));                
            if pixeltochange < j                    
                imagRshifted(i,j-pixeltochange,k) =...
                                                imagRshifted(i,j,k);
            end
        end
    end
    waitbar(i/size(imagR,1));
end

imagRshifted = uint8(imagRshifted);

% combine R,G,B to create 3D image

imag3D = imfuse(imagRshifted,imfuse(imagG,imagB));

% plot the desired images

if depictrgb == 0;    
    figure;imshow(imag3D);    
else 
    figure;imshow(imag3D);
    figure;imshow(imagR);
    figure;imshow(imagB);
    figure;imshow(imagG);
end

close(h);

end
```

[image]

As you can see the result is quite confusing (at least to me). At first there is a line splitting the final image in two parts (it seems like the formula has been applied only on the left part of the line leaving the right part untouched). Additionally the produced image is more like a reconstruction of random pixels rather than a combination of the R,G,B components.

Any ideas would be more than appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you post the original image? Also, do you know how the image should look like? And will the original image be always grayscale?

Comment: Also, a color image *is* technically a 3D image. It has x,y,C components. you describe your problem as a 2D to 3D conversion, but are using RGB values from the 2D image, and that makes no sense!

Comment: Dear Ander, thank you for your comment. Regarding your questions: 1) The original image is the one on the left (denoted as "before"), 2) The modified image should look sth like this http://postimg.org/image/5jdglfikt/. 3) The original image will be of type grayscale or truecolor (that's why I am using the first lines in my code). As for your second comment you are referring to the red,green,blue parts extraction? The initial image is 2D and the problem is a 2D to 3D conversion.

Comment: If the image is truecolor then it is 3D! Still I got it. let me try. Can you post the original image, without any editing?

Comment: Question about your formula: `a = x(i,j,k)*40/max(Rcomponent(:))`. This is a bit weird. `k` ? what is `k`? isn't it a 2D image? what is `Rcomponent`? the maximum of the `R` value? Isnt it a 2D gray image? it diesnt have R by definition.

Comment: To clarify, by the term 3D I mean with a 3D perspective (like the one in the attached link) and not a 3 dimensional matrix in general (like a truecolor image for example). Rcomponent is the image produced after subtracting blue and green from the original image. As a result imagR is a 3D matrix (but you already know that of course). That's why imagRshifted (produced by applying the formula in imagR) has a k inside the for loop.

Comment: You can find the original image at http://postimg.org/image/cv3vynjkd The thing is though that the original image could be also of a truecolor type (like this one http://postimg.org/image/47po0rrcz/) If it is not a big deal for you I would appreciate if you could point out the errors in the above code and guide me to the right direction. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My friend, you have 2 main problems: You don't know exactly what you are doing and you are using Matlab extremely inefficiently.

So lets go to what you need, and how to do it.

You described your problem relatively OK. Lets re-describe it.

**Starting from a grayscale image, create a color image with the red channel shifted by an amount given by the following equation: `shift = x_ij*40/max(x(:))` .**

There are missing things here, like: what to do if the shift goes out of the image? In this case we will assume that if the shift is too big, then make it zero.

lets start: First we are going to load an image, and if it is not grayscale, convert it to grayscale. I am using the following image:

[image]

```
% // same as you had
nameofimag='https://2.bp.blogspot.com/-db3zQg7geYA/UYqnvBriBeI/AAAAAAAAAHo/cv3Dy40mUFo/s1600/Meteosat_grid.jpg'
original = imread(nameofimag); % read file
imaginfos = imfinfo(nameofimag); % identify colortype
coltype = imaginfos(1).ColorType;
truecol = 'truecolor';

if strcmp(coltype,truecol) == 1 % convert to grayscale if needed
    originalgray = rgb2gray(original);
else
    originalgray = original;
end
```

Now we want to compute the shift per pixel we can do that in one line:

```
% compute shifts
shift=-round(  double(originalgray)  *40./double(max(originalgray(:))));
```

And we want to make sure that we don't go over the iamge, so we will compute the actual index (indY+shift) and check if that's inside the image

```
% get indexes
[indY,~]=meshgrid(1:size(originalgray,2),1:size(originalgray,1));

% Make sure we dont go out of the image
shift(indY+shift<=0)=0;
```

Now we have a proper shift, that we know its not going out. Realize, shift is a matrix `size(image)`, thus we have all we need.

Now, lets take the R channel and shift it. Realize, that the image is grayscale, thus R G and B are exactyl equal. we will then shift the original image.

```
% allocate memory
redshifted = zeros(size(originalgray,1),size(originalgray,2));

% actually shift red
for ii=1:size(originalgray,1)
    redshifted(ii,:)=originalgray(ii,indY(ii,:)+shift(ii,:));
end
```

Now that we have the red shifted, lets create a new image, that has RGB values, where GB are the original image and R the shifted image

```
colorImg=cat(3,redshifted,originalgray,originalgray);

imshow(colorImg)
```

This gives:

[image]

---

**Conclusion:** This code applies the shift to a grayscale image (or truecolor converted to grayscale) and generates a color image with the red shifted. Modifications need to be done if the original image is actually truecolor without the grayscale conversion, but these modifications will be minor, and mainly relate to changing `originalgray` in different places to proper RGB chanel access (e.g. `original(:,:,2)` is G).

**As a final note:** Realise that this will only look good with 3D glasses if the image is a depthmap. Else, you will get weird visual effect, as the color of an image has nothing to do with the depth of it (thus displacement of red)

Comment: Dear Ander, as I mentioned earlier this is the first time I tried to work with an image processing related task (as a result I am not familiar with the fundamentals of this science). That's why I decided to ask an expert on this field to help me clarifying the nature of the problem. In any case your reply is more than illuminating and helped me to realise which is the proper way to deal with such kind of problems. Once more I would like to thank you for your time.

Comment: @thp you are welcome! hope it helped! Notice also how the advantage of matlab is generally avoiding loops ;). Also, I would like to repeat, just in case: This will not good look unless the gray values of the image are the depth of it!

Comment: Your point is actually really accurate. This was the first thing I realised while reading your post. As for the depth, this is another quite useful information I will keep in mind. Thank you!